# Make operator OR in regular expression greedy

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to match `asd["]"]` inside `asd["]"] asd`

I use regular expression:

```
/([a-z]+?(\[[^,\]]*?\]|\[\".*\"\]))/u
```

but it gives me `asd["]`

If I change the order of OR elements in regular expression:

```
/([a-z]+?(\[\".*\"\]|\[[^,\]]*?\]))/u
```

I can get desired result, but I believe this way some other cases could not work. This is minified version of my regular expression.

How could I point to regular expression to chose longest possible match (act greedy)?

Edit:

With regexp:

```
/{((\"a\")|([^b]*)})/u
```

I get

```
{c {"a"}
```

from

```
{b{c {"a"} b}
```

In this case regexp chose second OR statement which is longer than first.

Comment: Please use code formatting (select and press Ctrl-K) to keep the markdown engine from trying to make your regex bold or italic where that changes its meanings.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, still learning the UI

Comment: What *other cases* are you talking about that could not work with the second one? Please provide more examples and the desired matches.

Comment: @TomTom the reason the engine used the second statement is not that is longer. The reason is that the engine tries to find a match from left to right. For the first `{` neither of the two alternations work. For the second `{` the first one (which is tried first!) does not work, because there is `"` after the `{`, so the engine tries `[^b]*}` and finds `{c {"a"}`. Greediness does not apply to alternations.

Comment: So I take for an answer that alternations work from left to right and cannot be set to act greedy. And that one should construct regular expressions, that most left alternations would match longest possible parts. If this is not possible you cannot use regular expressions.

Comment: @TomTom sure you can use regular expressions. But they are actually not powerful enough for your usecase. You are trying to match nested structures. That makes it a context-free language. Regular expressions cannot meaningfully handle this. There **is** a recursion construct in PCRE, but it will fail you, once you need to capture stuff within your nested structure. It is usually easier to walk the string yourself and count opening and closing brackets. This makes it also easier to ignore brackets inside quotes, or escaped brackets and similar things.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, in your two alternatives you made the one ungreedy that does not need it and left the one greedy that actually needs to be ungreedy. To solve your problem with regular expressions (although it will have some caveats), you should probably use negated character classes in any case:

```
'/([a-z]+?)\[([^"\[\]]*|"[^"]*")\]/'
```

This should work fine for your given example. It will find the innermost `asd[something here]` or `asd["something with [][] here"]`.

I was speaking of caveats. For the non-quoted case this cannot find nested occurrences. In `asd[b efg[something]]` it will match `efg[something]` and not the outer brackets. **However**, even if it could, then you would lose the inner match, because *matches cannot overlap*. If your desire is to find the outermost valid brackets (so only the full string in the given example), you should look into PCRE's [recursion capabilities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php). Just note that you have to decide on innermost or outermost. Neither `preg_match` nor `preg_match_all` will find you all nested matches.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seemed to work for me:

```
/([a-z]+(\[[^,]*\]|\[\".*\"\]))/
```

In it I simply removed the \] inside the [^,\]] section of your original regex, and removed all non-greedy wildcards, though they seemed to be having no effect anyway.
If you're looking for nested structures, looking for "*not closing symbol*" will never find you your longest match, as it will always stop at the first (innermost) closing character, so you have to pick something else that's unique inside the enclosure.